# Округление любых чисел до формата X.XX на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, округление

Есть несколько полей `input`, которые отображают результат вычисления функции. Практически всегда эти числа выглядят как `6579.186210714762`, `12571.174950660548` и тд.

Для округления я использую такую функцию:

```
const roundResult = function(value) {
  return (value !== '' && !Number.isNaN(Number(value))) ? (Number(value) / 1000).toFixed(2) : value;
}
```

Этого вполне хватает, чтобы округлять все вычисляемые числа до формата `X.XX`.

Сложности появляются, когда я пытаюсь импортировать в своё приложение сохранённый ранее проект с уже полученными вычислениями. Опуская детали, хочу сказать, что в этом случае в указанные инпуты попадают уже округлённые числа вида `6.58`, `12.57` и тд., которые всё та же функция `roundResult` повторно пытается округлить.

Я довольно долго копался, пытаясь решить эту, казалось бы, тривиальную задачу, но так и не смог придумать более-менее адекватного решения. Как можно обработать входящие числа таким образом, чтобы только сырые вычисления округлялись?

Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const roundResult = (value) => {
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    return NaN;
  }
  const isRoundNeeded = parseInt(value).toString().length > 2;

  if (isRoundNeeded) {
    return (value / 1000).toFixed(2);
  }
  return value;
};

console.log(roundResult(6579.186210714762));
console.log(roundResult(6.58));
```

Comment: Ваш вариант решения смог закрыть мой вопрос, с небольшими дополнениями)
Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Есть функция toFixed(), поддерживает округление

```
const numObj = 12345.6789;
numObj.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Да, мне известно об этой функции и в моём коде оно применяется, но без дополнительных условий toFixed не во всех случаях уместно.
Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Есть ли возможность превратить число в строку, разбить по точке и потом проверить длину элемента под индексом 1?
Я бы так и сделал

```
String(num).split('.')[1].length > 2
```

Эта проверка позволит узнать необходимо ли вызывать вашу функцию

Comment: Интересный способ, надо будет его запомнить)
Решение Александра Белоуса мне помогло
Спасибо за помощь